# How to get the query from the query id?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

When I do a search with    **"relevance-trace"** options, and use ***cts:relevance-info()*** method to get the score detail, i found:

```
<qry:key>#Unsigned-long#</qry:key>
```

Does any body know how to get the query detail from this query id?

```
<qry:score formula="scoreSum" computation="14706+14742+13923+15066+14263">72700</qry:score>
<qry:term weight="102.125">
    <qry:score formula="8*weight*logtf" computation="817*18">14706</qry:score>
    <qry:key>10230959290518878125</qry:key>
</qry:term>
<qry:term weight="102.375">
    <qry:score formula="8*weight*logtf" computation="819*18">14742</qry:score>
    <qry:key>10778582167837573966</qry:key>
</qry:term>
<qry:term weight="102.375">
    <qry:score formula="8*weight*logtf" computation="819*17">13923</qry:score>
    <qry:key>14635861007755384081</qry:key>
</qry:term>
```

Answer (score 2):

In general there should always be a qry:annotation element that tells you what the key means. You could try running xdmp:plan on your query to see if it gives you more information: sometimes you can piece together that an unannotated key is by looking at the trace elements as well.

Regardless you should report this as a bug: the query + your index settings.